# Using tkinter in function to return sublist from list input

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to define a callable function which should take a large list of items as input and through interaction with user return a sublist of checked out items.

I'm quite new to tkinter, but I have searched around stack after similar problems and used this to compose the following code. I know using global variables is a bad idea, and it actually does not work in this case. I've tried to append all the variables of the checked out boxes to a global lst and then tried to return this list, but does not work. Is it possible to make a new function to export the list or use widget?

```
items = ['screw driver', 'belt', 'nut','hammer','tape','ducked tape','drill']
def choose_items(item_list):
import tkinter as tk

class App(object):
    def __init__(self):

        def click(event):
            button.config(bg='green')

        root = tk.Tk()
        root.title('Choose items')
        text = tk.Text(root, cursor='arrow')
        vsb = tk.Scrollbar(root, command=text.yview)
        button = tk.Button(root, text='Add items', command=addtolist)
        button2 = tk.Button(root, text='Quit', command=root.destroy)
        text.configure(yscrollcommand=vsb.set)

        button.pack(side='top')
        button2.pack(side='bottom')
        button.bind('<Button-1>',click)
        vsb.pack(side='right',fill='y')
        text.pack(side='left', fill='both', expand=True)

        global varList
        varList = []

        for i in range(len(items)):
            var = tk.StringVar()
            cb = tk.Checkbutton(text, text=item_list[i], variable=var,
                                onvalue=item_list[i], offvalue='')
            varList.append(var)
            text.window_create('end', window=cb)
            text.insert('end','\n')
        text.configure(state='disabled')
        root.mainloop()

def addtolist():
    global lst
    lst = []
    for i in varList:
        if i.get() != ' ':
            lst.append(i.get())

if __name__=='__main__':
    App()

return lst

choose_items(items)
```

I expect the output to be the items that the user has checked of but get the following error message:
NameError: name 'lst' is not defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `return` within your `addtolist` function. Also `addtolist` should be a class method instead of a separate function since you are looping over the items in `varList`, which also should be made a class attribute instead of declaring `global`.

```
class App(object):
    def __init__(self):
        ...

        self.varList = []

        for i in range(5):
            var = tk.StringVar()
            cb = tk.Checkbutton(text, text=f"Item {i}", variable=var,
                                onvalue=i, offvalue='')
            self.varList.append(var)
            text.window_create('end', window=cb)
            text.insert('end', '\n')
        ...

    def addtolist(self):
        lst = []
        for i in self.varList:
            if i.get() != ' ':
                lst.append(i.get())
        return lst
```

Comment: Thanks alot Henry!
Used your advice and a few more changes mainly to the command of the "Add items"-button: `command = App.addtolist(self)` and instead of running App() I made a variable for the list: `chosen_items = App().addtolist()` which is being returned.

Comment: `command = App.addtolist(self)` won't work. You need to pass the command as a reference, which should be without the parenthesis `()`, i.e.  `command = App.addtolist`. Also if you are setting up this command within the class, it should be `command=self.addtolist` instead.

Comment: After som trial and error it worked using `command = lambda: App.addtolist(self))` and `return App().addtolist()`. I kind of just used the indices for deciding which of the items in the input list was checked off and append these using `lst.append(item_list[i])`. Might not be the best pythonic way, but solved my issue :)